# Chat application using Socket programming android

Tags: android, sockets

Is it possible to do a chat between client and server (two android devices) using socket programming in android?If possible,anybody please offer me a help.Even a link is acceptable.

Comment: it is possible and its easy with okhttp websocket check out this example https://github.com/pushpendra-spartan/android-websockets

Comment: do you want to involve some centralised server or you want devices should behave as server and client ?

Comment: I just need chat between two devices over same wifi network.Is it possible to do without centralised server

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. you can use socket programming and create chat application with 2+ devices. one device must act as server and others have to be client. if your want to your server to be android device and don't want have web server side it does not need an internet connection. just a access point or one mobile hotsopt is enough. but all device must be connect to same hotspot or access point.